# fold expression in assignment

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, generic-programming, fold-expression

I am trying to use a fold expression to simplify some code. In following code, I am trying to insert elements into an array, but the fold expression does not compile

```
struct test {
  std::string cmd[20];
  test() {
    int i = 0;
    auto insert = [&](auto... c) {
      assert(i < 20);
      (cmd[i++] = c), ...;
    };
    insert("c");
    insert("c", "c2");
  }
};
```

compilers complains about missing ';'

Comment: enclosing `(cmd[i++] = c), ...` into brackets seems to solve the problem

Comment: maybe `assert(i + sizeof...(c) < 20);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) have to be parenthesized. Hence:

```
((cmd[i++] = c), ...);
```

The inner parentheses are necessary as well.